# Ionic 3, sidemenu transparente

Tags: ionic3

Tengo una app Ionic 3 con un sidemenu, y quisiera hacer el **background transparente**, pero no el texto del header, footer y del content. Algo así como opacity 0.45, pero cuando lo hago, el texto también toma la opacity, cosa que no deseo. Les agradeceré la ayuda que me puedan brindar, muchas gracias !

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menú</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
    <ion-avatar class="avatar" >
      <img src="../../assets/imgs/sssss.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item detail-none block menuClose *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p.page)">
        <ion-icon item-start [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
        {{ p.title }}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer >
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-row align-items-center>
        <ion-col>
            <button ion-button full clear icon-left (click)="logout()">
            Logout
            </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>
</ion-menu> 
<ion-nav #content main [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-inner .item {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.ion-header {
    background-color: transparent; 
}
.menu-inner > ion-header, 
.menu-inner > ion-content, 
.menu-inner > ion-footer, {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.toolbar-title {
    color : #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta está basada en opiniones y no en un problema en concreto, por lo que te invito a que realices el [recorrido o tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)
de la comunidad por si no lo has hecho. El motivo principal de la comunidad es ayudar a solucionar ciertos problemas que puedan surgir en
el camino de un programador, por lo que tu pregunta es muy general como para ser considerada una pregunta que termine en una respuesta
válida y por último lee sobre[¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Debes aportar código que nos ayude a ayudarte, es complicado simplemente con lo que has expresado en la pregunta.

Comment: Creí que con solicitar ayuda acerca de como hacer un sidemenu transparente bastaba, como es css entendí que no hacía falta código. Igual te agradezco tu tiempo y tu preocupación por la formalidad.

Comment: Si, todo debe ser adjuntado, porque aca intentamos ayudarte. Pero debes mostrarnos que has intentado, que es lo que crees que no te da lo que esperas. Además de que tu etiqueta es de Ionic, y creo que tu problema radica en Sass o en Css (obviamente porque lo expresaste en tu comentario). Entonces, entre mayor información mucho mas facil será responder a tus dudas

Comment: No, edita tu pregunta. Arriba donde está mi primer comentario hay unos enlaces que dicen "compartir", "editar y "reportar". Da click en editar y te llevará a tu pregunta para que puedas agregar todo lo que consideres importante.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya edité la pregunta original, espero lograr ayuda

Comment: Gracias jecorrales

Comment: Mira, si nadie te responde, para mañana te tendré alguna respuesta.